# ffmpeg add silent audio channel

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm creating seperate mp4s from jpg & png files, then concatenating them. This process is working well. What I want to do now though is concatenate files with an audio contents to them. This isn't working when a silent movie is first.

I have no idea on how to add the silent audio track to the image based mp4's. I've tried adapting the successful code for creating the mp4 but it didn't work

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/create_reel/images/holding-00006/img00002.png \
 -filter_complex '
     [0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,
          trim=duration=5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5
     [v0];
     [0:a]aevalsrc=05[a0];  
     [v0][a0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]' 
  -map '[v][a]' /tmp/create_reel/mp4s/file_00003.mp4
```

Anything with an a between [] was part of the experiment.

Am I headed down the right track or just showing my lack knowledge with ffmeg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/create_reel/images/holding-00006/img00002.png \
 -filter_complex "
 [0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,
      trim=duration=5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5
 [v0];
 aevalsrc=0:d=5[a0];  
 [v0][a0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map "[v]" -map "[a]" /tmp/create_reel/mp4s/file_00003.mp4
```

**Edit**:

This can be compacted to

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/create_reel/images/holding-00006/img00002.png \
-f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=5
-vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,trim=duration=5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5"
-pix_fmt yuv420p /tmp/create_reel/mp4s/file_00003.mp4
```

Comment: Why use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` instead of keeping all filtering within the filtergraph with `format=yuv420p`? I usually prefer anullsrc for silent audio generation, but it doesn't really matter which is used.

Comment: That just skipped my mind. What's the advantage of `anullsrc` - speed?

Comment: Yeah, speed is the "advantage"...if you're just encoding audio and doing days and days of encoding. It lacks `d` option though which is nice to have (but `-t` input can be used instead).